# Is there a way to access a scoped service from a custom Nlog renderer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I created a scoped service called applicationcontext in asp.net core webapi in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationContext>();
```

There is a middleware adding extra information to the object through

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    string? loggedInUserUuid = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    if (loggedInUserUuid != null)
        applicationContext.CurrentUserUuid = Guid.Parse(loggedInUserUuid);
    await _next(context);
}
```

I created an NLog custom renderer and tried to access the object, but failed.
I passed in the service provider through

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance = (Type type) =>
{
    // custom target.
    if (type == typeof(HelloWorldLayoutRenderer))
        return new HelloWorldLayoutRenderer(app.Services);
    else
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
};
```

and in the renderer

```
protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
{            
    builder.Append("hello world!");
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var applicationContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationContext>();
        builder.Append(applicationContext?.CurrentUserUuid);
    }
```

The thing is scope here is a different scope from the webapi request scope. I can't get the currentUser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Think the usual approach is either to extract from `HttpContext` directly (LayoutRenderer inherits from AspNetLayoutRendererBase in NLog.Web). Or to have custom middleware to capture scope-value and inject into `HttpContext.Items` and extract value using existing [${aspnet-item}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-HttpContext-Item-Layout-Renderer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RolfKristensen
In the end I created a renderer as following to access the httpcontext items directly.

```
[LayoutRenderer("user")]
public class HelloWorldLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
{
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var context = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        string? loggedInUserUuid = context?.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        builder.Append(loggedInUserUuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice [${aspnet-user-claim:ClaimTypes.Name}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-User-Claim-layout-renderer) can be used to output different [ClaimTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes) values.

Comment: Notice that `[ThreadAgnostic]` should only be used when captured context is thread-independent. All LayoutRenderers that extracts values from HttpContext can never be `[ThreadAgnostic]`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer